# ExpandableListView анимация Expand Collapse групп

Tags: expandablelistview, android, listview, анимация

Собственно вопрос:  
Как добавить анимацию для сворачивания-разворачивания групп в `ExpandableListView`?  
Находил в интернете решения типа "переделать на обычный `ListView`, и анимировать вручную, но этого делать очень не хочется...

**UPD** Специально для тех, кто не понимает с первого раза:
Вариант типа "переделать на обычный `ListView`" **не интересует**! Гуглом я пользоваться умею, нашел и сам 100500 таких решений.

Comment: Пробовали [это][1] ?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780292/slide-down-effect-on-expandablelistview

Comment: @DroidAlex не пробовал, но видел. Как я уже писал, находил решения для обычного ListView. Это решение - переделать на обычный ListView.

Comment: Ну на самом деле анимация уже есть, вопрос в том как ее поменять на свою. Если я правильно понял. Попробуйте найти исходник ExpandableListView, наследовать его и реализовать нужную логику. А потом выложите на GitHub и все будут довольны. Но я чувствую это можно сделать какой-нибудь анимацией, может ObjectAnimator-ом.

Comment: @DroidAlex пітался я смотреть исходники ExpandableListView, но с первого раза не нашел там нужного мне... Попробую еще раз

Comment: Можно попробовать в адаптере, реализующем ExpandableListAdapter прикрутить анимацию. А еще можно попробовать при клике вытащить нужную ViewGroup и анимировать ее. Но мне эти оба способа кажется не кошерными как-то уж. И видите в чем соль: раз это сделать можно не так очевидно, то возникает вопрос: а нужно ли это вообще реализовывать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот [это](http://upadhyayjiteshandroid.blogspot.ru/2013/03/android-exapandlistview-animation.html). Если не поможет, то мой вам совет:
Попробуйте создать класс, унаследованный от ExpandableListView, и написать там свой код с анимацией при сворачивании. А потом этот класс используйте так же, как и обычный ExpandableListView:
xml

`<имя.вашего.пакета.Класс
    android:layout... />`